# How can a run a middleware function a single time when I am using Cluster in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I am using clusters in my node.js server and I have a middlewere function that is saving weekly some data to db. The issue is that I am using three workers and this function is executed three times and it saves 3 documents in the DB. How can I avoid this and still use clusters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const http = require('http');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);
  // execute the one time function


  // Fork workers.
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
  });
} else {
  // Workers can share any TCP connection
  // In this case it is an HTTP server
  http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('hello world\n');
  }).listen(8000);

  console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);
}
```

you can do that by executing it inside the if statement or where your master code executes. this way you can just run it once.

https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

Answer (score 0):

Your nodejs program can [tell whether it's the maste](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_ismaster)r with `cluster.isMaster()`.

Your master can update your weekly data.  Or, if all your workers have to generate their own data, they can do that, then the master can read it all and create just one document.